# "using" for "<template <class> class T>"

Tags: c++, templates

Not sure whether I go to far with template programming this time. I try to pass around a template template parameter. The question came up from a real problem, but I will solve that problem differently now. So the question is more or less "academic"

First, I try to "store" `F_` in a struct which will be used as a template parameter:

```
template <class M_, template <class> class F_>
struct Conf{
    using F = F_; // Problem 1: F_ is not a type!
    using M = M_;
};
```

`F` is then read from the struct and used to instantiate `func`:

```
template <class CONF> // CONF is a Conf<x, y>
void call(){
    using F = typename CONF::F; // Problem 2: F_ is still not a type!
    func<F>();
}
```

And func is:

```
template <template <class> F>
void func(){
  F<MyType>::call();
}
```

The problem is: I can not use using to "store" `F`. What can I do to be able to pass `F` around in a struct?

Comment: `F_` is a template type. So you'd need to write `using F = F_<int>` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should template your `using` like this :

```
template <class M_, template <class> class F_>
struct Conf{
    template <class T>
    using F = F_<T>;
    using M = M_;
};
```

Comment: Note that `F` and `F_` are considered different (for specialization for example) whereas `F<T>` and `F_<T>` are identical.

Comment: @Jarod42 are you certain?  I vaguely recall a standard defect being raised over if that is true or not and in what situations.

Comment: @Yakk: No longer when clang and gcc disagree :-( [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f2e20c8f6845995)

Comment: @Jarod42 *nod*, IIRC, the rule became `using` declarations that are pure aliases (insert technical standardese) are the same as the thing they are aliasing, while those which are not are different.